# Puting Admob ads at the bottom of WebView having fill_parent height layout

Tags: android, android-layout, admob

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="myID"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/search_contentDescription"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search" />

   <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/search"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:hint="@string/edit_hint"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <WebView
    android:id="@+id/result"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/edit" />

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My admob ads is currently located on top. How can I move it to the bottow of the WebView? Changing `android:layout_height` of the WebView to `wrap_content` is not what I want. The height of WebView should be filled vertically to the maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you don't just put your adView just after your relative layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/search_contentDescription"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search" />

   <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/search"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:hint="@string/edit_hint"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <WebView
    android:id="@+id/result"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/edit" />

</RelativeLayout>

<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="myID"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

If it doesn't work you can change your LinearLayout by a RelativeLayout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="myID"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/adView" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/search_contentDescription"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search" />

       <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/edit"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/search"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:hint="@string/edit_hint"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <WebView
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/edit" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I tried this but it is not work. I got java.lang.ClassCastException: android.webkit.WebView cannot be cast to android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView error.

Comment: Yes, I forgot a quote in my example, it's now edited :)

Comment: The second method works for me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Change your `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout` and use

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

in both the `LinearLayout` and `WebView`

Answer (score 0):

Do something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search" />

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/edit"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/search"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:hint=" string/edit_hint"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/result"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/edit" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="myID"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, but setting an explicit height may not be a good idea since the screen size varies widely across Android phone.